# ImapProtocol.readResponse timeout Javamail

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap

When there is no response from the server and I still make `readresponse()`, It hangs there. Is there any timeout for this function?

```
Properties prop =new Properties(); 
prop.setProperty("mail.imap.port","993");
prop.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
prop.setProperty("mail.imaps.timeout", "5000");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop);
IMAPProtocol protocol=new IMAPProtocol("username","imap.gmail.com",993,true,session.getDebugOut(), session.getProperties(),true);
protocol.login("username","password");
protocol.select("inbox");
protocol.idleStart();
protocol.readResponse();
```

Answer (score 1):

The [com.sun.mail.imap documentation](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html) has a table at the bottom that lists all of the session properties you can set for IMAP. Set the `mail.imap.timeout` and or `mail.imaps.timeout` as the timeout in milliseconds.

Comment: If you are using IMAP over SSL you have to set the `mail.imaps.timeout` property.  What version of JavaMail are you using?

Comment: am using imap over ssl . javamail version 1.4.3

Comment: Properties prop =new Properties();
prop.setProperty("mail.imap.port","993");   prop.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");  prop.setProperty("mail.imaps.timeout", "5000");  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop);

            IMAPProtocol protocol=new IMAPProtocol("username","imap.gmail.com",993, true,session.getDebugOut(), session.getProperties(),true);
            protocol.login("username","password");
            protocol.select("inbox");
            protocol.idleStart();               
            protocol.readResponse();

Comment: Use Session.getInstance.  Don't create an IMAPProtocol object.  Use Session.getStore() and set `mail.store.protocol` property to control the type of store.